# search form - 2 values in 1 option

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have this code into a search form:

```
<select name="rentbuy">
<option value="buy">Buy</option>
<option value="rent">Rent</option>
<option value="rent/week">Rent/week</option>
</select>
```

This is what I want to do:

```
<select name="rentbuy">
<option value="buy">Buy</option>
<option value="rent rent/week">Rent</option>
</select>
```

So when someone chooses "Rent" I want the form to get both values "rent" and "rent/week".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple attribute on select element :

```
<select name="rentbuy" multiple="multiple">
 <option value="buy">Buy</option>
 <option value="rent" selected="selected">Rent</option>
 <option value="rent/week"  selected="selected">Rent/week</option>
</select>
```

Here is a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/v2wHS/

Comment: I don't want to show the option "rent/week" in the list and I want it to be dropdown.

Comment: Ok, so you have to do some javascript too. As I don't know how you write this form in Wordpress, I cannot help you more. Give us more informations.

Answer (score 0):

I have this code into the theme, maybe helps with something:

```
$search_buyorrent = "";
if (get_option('wp_search_bor') == "Yes") {
if (isset($_COOKIE['rentbuy']) && $_COOKIE['rentbuy'] != '') {
$search_buyorrent = $_COOKIE['rentbuy'];
} else {
if (isset($_POST['rentbuy'])) {
$search_buyorrent = trim($_POST['rentbuy']);
}
}
} else {
$search_buyorrent = '';
}
```

And another snippet here:

```
if ($search_buyorrent == "buy" || $search_buyorrent == "") {
$query ="SELECT p.* FROM $wpdb->posts p, $wpdb->postmeta p1
WHERE p.ID = p1.post_id AND p1.meta_key='price_value' AND convert(p1.meta_value,        signed) BETWEEN '$search_pricemin_buy' AND '$search_pricemax_buy'";
$spm = getIds( $query );
$_ids = ( !empty($spm) ? ( !empty($_ids) ? array_intersect( $_ids, $spm) : "" ) : "" );
}
```

Comment: `isset($_COOKIE['rentbuy']) && $_COOKIE['rentbuy'] != ''` equals `!empty($_COOKIE['rentbuy'])`